# Retrieving object from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray and I would like to use data from it in another view. I read up and found we can use indexOfObject to read data, but my NSMutableArray has multiple values, and I do not know how to obtain a particular field from the NSMutableArray.

Any help would be great appreciated.

I'm currently stuck at my IBAction onStartPressed. at the line

```
    self.clueHint.text = ds[0].initialClue;
//or
    self.clueHint.text = ds objectAtIndex:0 initialClue;
```

I displayed my other file and code which is involved.

ClueData.h
    #import

```
@interface ClueData : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * clueName;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * initialClue;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * clueHint1;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * clueHint2;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString * clueAnswer;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage * clueImage;
@end
```

ClueDataDAO.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClueData.h"
@interface ClueDataDAO : NSObject
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * clueDataArray;

-(NSMutableArray *) PopulateDataSource;
@end
```

ClueDataDAO.m

```
#import "ClueDataDAO.h"

@implementation ClueDataDAO
@synthesize clueDataArray;
-(NSMutableArray *) PopulateDataSource
{
    clueDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     ClueData * sampleData = [[ClueData alloc]init];

    sampleData.clueName = @"Tropical Fruit Tree";
    sampleData.initialClue = @"Where all the Tropical trees are planted.";
    sampleData.clueHint1 = @"It is located at Area 10";
    sampleData.clueHint2 = @"It could be found near Eco Lake";
    sampleData.clueAnswer = @"Fruit tree collection";
    NSString * file=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"FruitTreeCollection" ofType:@"jpg"];
    sampleData.clueImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file];
    [clueDataArray addObject:sampleData];
    sampleData=nil;

    return clueDataArray;
}
@end
```

GamePageViewController.M

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    daoDS = [[ClueDataDAO alloc]init];
    self.ds = daoDS.PopulateDataSource; //load pre-build NSMutableArray
    self.answer.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {

    //initiate load object
// stuck at here :(

    ClueData * currentClue = [ds objectAtIndex:0]; // app got terminate at this line of code
self.clueHint.text = [currentClue initialClue];


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my array has multiple fields"? Well, that's why it's called an array and not a primitive type... Also, **do use whitespace.** `@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray*clueDataArray;` just downright hurts. Similarly, this question is **not related to Xcode in any way.**

Comment: I think he mean: every object got multiple items, so the basics of an NSDict or a (custom) class as item of the array.

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm a noob...Still New...

Comment: @YangJieDomodomo I see, but that's not an excuse for at least not formatting your code to a readable level and not reading the available high-quality official documentation of Apple about all the classes you're trying to use. See, I was a newcomer once too, but I didn't need to ask such questions on StackOverflow to learn what I know now.

Comment: Apple documentation for objectAtIndex only show 1 field per object. i tried googling, but couldn't find any example or sample where they were using multiple field per object. that's why i had to come ask in SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the IBAction, first cast/save it to the correct var, like

ClueData * sampleData = [ds objectAtIndex:0];

then self.clueHint.text= [sampleData initialClue];

as example

Comment: I got "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'" this error when I add in the line "ClueData * sampleData = [ds objectAtIndex:0];"

Comment: then your array is empty... So print your array. Make the array as a class-variable and be sure to init the array at the class init, or viewDidLoad, or ...

Comment: ok it work now. I made an error somewhere else which wipe the array... thank you jelle